# Error import with 'shamilton_filter_log' from 'statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching._hamilton_filter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, markov-models

I tried to compile MarkovSwitching.py from statsmodels ([link description here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/tsa/regime_switching/markov_switching.py)) in python, but I have the follwoing error,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'shamilton_filter_log' from 'statsmodels.tsa.regime_switching._hamilton_filter'  (C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\regime_switching\_hamilton_filter.cp37-win_amd64.pyd)
```

And I don't kown how solve this. Furthermore, I upgrade the statsmodels using '' pip install statsmodels --upgrade'', but doesn't work.

I don't know how to solve this problem, any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to tell from your description what might be going wrong, since there could be many problems with your setup.

It looks like maybe you have installed Statsmodels v0.10 via Conda or pip and have then downloaded the development version of `markov_switching.py`. The development version has new functions that v0.10 does not have, and this is my guess about why you are getting the error.

You might try installing the release candidate of v0.11, using: `pip install statsmodels==0.11.0rc1`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! I've been using python for a short time, but Statsmodels has helped me a lot.
I am doing some Markov Switching tasks, in particular, to determine that “it enters as input” on line class MarkovSwitching(tsbase.TimeSeriesModel) and  def smooth; And in both cases determine what the outputs are. This is why I tried to compile markov_switching.py, but I have the import error 'shamilton_filter_log'.